# Helm: how to add elements to a list of default values?

Tags: helm

It might be a very simple question, though somewhy I can't google the answer.

Let's assume we have a Helm chart with some default values such as the following:

```
parameters:
- parameterName: parameter1
  value: value1
- parameterName: parameter2
  value: value2
```

I need to add an element to this list in my extra values file. Of course, I can just duplicate the default values to my extra values file and add my extra parameters to them:

```
parameters:
- parameterName: parameter1
  value: value1
- parameterName: parameter2
  value: value2
- parameterName: parameterN
  value: valueN
```

I don't like this idea, because when the maintainers of this Helm chart change their defaults, my defaults will override instead of following them.

What is the proper way to add my `parameterN` to the default values?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6569, this is not possible. This is by design, because lists are designed to be used as immutable data.
The answers on that github issue suggest to use a map instead of a list, if this is possible in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Kustomize for this, with a json9602 patch as described in https://skryvets.com/blog/2019/05/15/kubernetes-kustomize-json-patches-6902/#append-to-a-list.
A nice method to combine Kustomize with Helm: https://austindewey.com/2020/07/27/patch-any-helm-chart-template-using-a-kustomize-post-renderer/.